# Dynamically updating query params

Tags: ember.js

In ember.js how do you dynamically update a query param?

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    myQuery: "test",

    queryParams: ["myQuery"],

    actions: {
       click() {
          this.set("myQuery", "update query param");
      }
    }
});


export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    myQuery: { refreshModel: true }
  },
  model(params) {
    console.log(params)
  }
});
```

When the action is fired the model hook should be called again, unless I am wrong?

[Please find an example here](https://ember-twiddle.com/69ff6d0319c6b48dddef000f5c3f2fd4?openFiles=templates.components.my-button.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-button.hbs&route=%2Ftest), navigate to the `/test` route and click the button. Inside the console you can see that the model hook is not fired again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is related with the fact that you are not using `action` helper to pass action to `my-button` component and passing the action like `click=actions.click` from within `test.hbs`. When you do so; `this` context to run for the `click` function is not properly set by Emberjs. That is if you debug your code you are going to see that; this context within your twiddle when `click` action inside `test.js` controller is actually set to `my-button` component. This means you are just setting `myQuery` property of `my-button` component; which does nothing to the `myQuery` property of the controller; hence the controller's property is not updated so the model hook is not run again even if you declare it as `refreshModel: true`.

What can you do? Just use the `action` helper and everything will work fine. Just check the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ea7665dff46e24d8656e7d00f1d50073?openFiles=controllers.test.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-button.hbs&route=%2Ftest%3FmyQuery%3Dupdate%2520query%2520param). The url will be updated and model hook will be executed as you wish. Remember that; `action` helper is crucial to set to the correct `this` context even if it seems like a normal function passing and calling.